# Styling GeoServer with CSS, what are the gt-labels?

Tags: geoserver, css, geoserver-css-module

I use CSS to style layers in GeoServer. Some style parameters user gt-as a prefix. Like *gt-label-follow-line* or *gt-label-repeat*. What does gt stand for and where is the documentation for using those parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any reference to `gt-label-follow-line` in the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/properties.html) (or any where else). There are references to `label-follow-line` and `label-repeat` though.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Ian! I manage to find it in [some very old docs](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver-history/blob/master/doc/en/user/source/community/css/properties.rst). I'll just skip the `-gt-` part in the future.

Comment: probably best to ignore historic copies of the docs